# specify values from external configuration file

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to specify values from a configuration file in JMeter (for multiple jmx files)?

1. Eg. in the following image, I have provided the `webserver` as `localhost`. In future, I might want to change it to `domain` or `ip` of a `test` server.  Is is possible that I use a variable say `WEB_SERVER` and the value is picked from external file where I can specify the value of the web server?

[image]

1.1) Can I specify values such that multiple `.jmx` files use the same value. Eg. I have multiple files and I want that all of them use the same configuration file to pick the value of the web server.

Comment: found this helpful tutorial - https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/01/14/flexible-test-plans/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [tutorial suggests](https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/01/14/flexible-test-plans/) use JMeter properties, specifically you can share `user.properties` with your shared properties

Then in jmx file/Test Plan get property value using `__P` function

```
${__P(propName, defaultValue)}
```

Or in JSR223 script

```
 props.get("propName");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 options:

1. Use [Property File Reader](https://www.vinsguru.com/jmeter-property-file-reader-a-custom-config-element/) custom plugin
2. Use *user.properties* file where you can override various [JMeter Properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) and define your new custom ones, JMeter automatically picks up all the values provided in this file
3. Use your custom .properties file (with name value pairs in form of `foo=bar`), you will need to provide the file location via [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) like:

   ```
   jmeter -q /path/to/your/custom.properties -t test.jmx ...
   ```